# php code to return value based on array?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Basically i have 2 pages;  Page1.php and Page2.php... On page 1 the user can enter their Postcode and Property Value, Upon submit the page will POST to page2.php.

I am looking for help to have a small script return (echo or print) a value back to the customer based on the property value, To make it simple i will have the property value set within ranges so for example:

```
£0        =>   £100,000  -->  Return as £125
£101,000  =>   £200,000  -->  Return as £195
£201,000  =>   £300,000  -->  Return as £275
```

And so on...

I was hoping to have the script return the output variable so i can use the echo function to show the default value set for the range entered by the user within a set css box on the page.

So if i entered page1.php as a customer and i enter my postcode and enter my property value as £225,000 *(This will not be used as a selected option it will be down to the user to enter this in manually same as Postcode box)*

When i submit this and get taken to page2.php the script will realize i have entered within the range of £201,000 - £300,000 and return the default value using the echo variable function.

*I hope i have explained the best I can as I really am learning the basics and still trying to get use to certain terms. Any help is greatly appreciated and would like to thank you for taking the time out to read this post including the time to comment and help.*

Comment: What do you have so far? And to some up - you want to take a number from a user field and output the appropriate range on the next page?

Comment: Hi wedstorm, i don't have anything so far as it was something i had thought of today and was not sure if it was possible. The user will enter the property price in (£) manually to a text box as such, The form will post to page2 and depending on what range the property price falls under the script will return the default value set for that specific range. Does that make sense? Thanks for taking time to help :)

Comment: it's all very doable but you need to narrow the issues down more. Overall question is far too broad

Comment: We could just spit out some code but where is the fun in that? Are you familiar with $_GET and $_POST? How about arrays? Jrad51 is right in that you will get better answers if you narrow down your question into more specific pieces. Get as far as you can on your own, this is very doable and a great beginner exercise.

Comment: i understand the $_GET and $_POST methods and understand that using GET will send the values within the url, What i am trying to find out is if we could set default values for anything entered within set ranges. so any figure between say £100,000 and £200,000 entered by the user would return our default price for the product based on the user property price, Our services go by geolocation and property price so each 100,000 bumps the overall price up a little. I can probably contribute to the code once i sort of figure what basics i need to be following, Do we use Arrays?

Comment: i thought of something like this:   

$range = range($min, $max);
if(in_array($num, $range)){

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Page 1** contain the form where the user enter his input:

```
<form action="page2.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="userinput" placeholder="Type.." />
  <input type="submit" value="Send to page 2" name="submitPrice" />
</form>
```

Have a look at the **name attribute** on the input element.

**Page 2**

This page process the data from the form.

One way you can do it is to have a lookup table storing the
ranges:

```
$data = array(
    array(
        'min' => 0,
        'max' => 100,
        'value' => 125
    ),
    array(
        'min' => 101,
        'max' => 200,
        'value' => 195
    ),
    array(
        'min' => 201,
        'max' => 300,
        'value' => 275
    )
);
```

Now you can use this table to check if the user input is in the range between *min* and *max*. I've used `array_filter` in this example:

```
function getAdjustedPrice($price, &$table) {
    $priceData = current(array_filter($table, function($value) use(&$price) {
        return $value['min'] <= $price && $value['max'] >= $price;
    }));
    return $priceData['value'];
}
```

And to check that it works:

```
$input = 101;
printf("User entered: %d, adjusted price: %d", 
       $input, 
       getAdjustedPrice($input, $data));
```

`$input` is just static as of now, so we might want to replace it with the
value from the form. The value is stored in the superglobal array `_POST`:

```
$input = intval($_POST["userinput"]);
```

*"userinput"* is the name we used on the input element in the form on page 1.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to help i greatly appreciate it, As i am still learning the basics both these answers are advanced for me at the moment and i am trying to see what works best and how to implement these. What variable would i use on page1 to post to page2 where the above code will run to return the value. As i am learning the basics i am little confused as to what variable is to used if that makes sense? My code where the user enters the property price is as follows:

Comment: <label class="required">Property value</label>
   <input id="property-value" type="text" name="value" />

Comment: I've updated my answer with a brief description on how you send the value from page A to page B.

Comment: Thanks msfoster, Will give get the code added asap im working on page 1 right now but will be ready soon :)  Will let you know how things go.  Thanks again.

Comment: Going to bed now, I'll answer tomorrow if you have any further questions. Good luck!

Comment: sorry i have been away due to my girlfriend being heavily pregnant, I will continue from where we left off now.. and will try to implement the code above. sorry for the delay and will accept the top answer asap :) Thanks for taking the time to help and i do apologize for the delay on response.

Comment: Everything works great, The only problem i have is what the script is "printing"  so for example this section of the script "<?php $input = intval($_POST["userinput"]);
printf("User entered: %d, adjusted price: %d", 
       $input, 
       getAdjustedPrice($input, $data)); ?> is printing the user input value and our default value assigned in the script, How do i go about removing the "User entered: %d," and only keep the Default assigned value to be either printed or using "echo" the reason is because i need to display only the "adjusted price" in a certain css/html box within the page. Thanks

Comment: You can do just `echo getAdjustedPrice($input,$data);`.  I usually use `printf` for formatting, rather than concatenating strings and variables.

Comment: After trying both examples and messing around with loads of other code / data they both work perfectly. The problem i now have is how can i accept both answers as the top answer! I feel bad because both yourself and Wedstorm have taken your own time out to help me and write the code, You was the first person to provide the code and was the first person to help so i will accept your answer as the top answer and i very much appreciate the time taken to help. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is the code for page1.php:

```
<form action="page2.php" method="get">
    <input name="userfield" id="thiscanbedifferent" type="text">
 </form>
```

This code for page2.php will make the user input safe to use:

```
$userPrice = $_GET['userfield'];//The $_GET variable has all the values from your form as long as you specify method: get. Remember that users are both incompetent and devious, and that you can never trust their input. Always clean and check it!!
$userPrice = preg_replace('/[^0-9.]/','',$userPrice);//This is called a regular expression, it filters out stuff we don't want. This one gets rid of characters that are not in the range 0-9, or "."

$userPrice = floatval($userPrice);//This turns the cleaned value into a number
```

This code will convert an arbitrary number into a range.

```
$rangeLabels = ["$0 - $100,000",
"$101,000-$200,000",
"$201,000-$300,000"];//labels for pricing. can be extended indefinately, as needed

$rangePricing = [125,175,195];//pricing steps. can be extended indefinately, as needed

$rangeIndex = floor($userPrice/100000);//100000 can be adjusted to any increment you would like, just be sure to update labels accordingly
//$rangeIndex = floor(($userPrice-1000)/100000);//this alternate equation makes values such as 100,999 fall below $101,000. My literal (probably wrong) interpretation of your range labels.

if($rangeIndex < 0 || $rangeIndex > count($rangePricing)){
   die('Number is out of range!');//Use better error handling in production
}

echo 'The user has selected the price $' . floatval($userPrice) . ' which falls under into the range ' . $rangeLabels[$rangeIndex] . ', for which the pricing is ' . $rangePricing[$rangeIndex] . '<br>';
```

Comment: Wedstorm thanks for taking time to help i really appreciate this. As i just said below to msfoster Due to still learning the basics and both these answers are really advanced for me at the moment. Im confused as to what variable i would use to send from page1 to page2 where the above code will run and return the value.  Page1 is where the user will input the property price in the following text box: <label class="required">Property value</label> <input id="property-value" type="text" name="value" /> so am i right in thinking i need to change the id="" and name ="" to be the same as the script?

Comment: You are partially right, name needs to be the same as the key you pass to $_GET, but id doesn't effect it.

Comment: Hi Wedstorm, sorry i have been away a few days as my girlfriend is heavily pregnant. in terms of the script for some reason dreamweaver is giving syntax error for both these lines, $rangeLabels = ["$0 - $100,000",
"$101,000-$200,000",
"$201,000-$300,000"];//labels for pricing. can be extended indefinately, as needed

$rangePricing = [125,175,195];//pricing steps. can be extended indefinately, as needed
( I have tried to remove the $ USD sign from the $100,000 and so on.. as i thought that could be playing a part but it seems to not)  Any ideas?  Thanks for taking time to write script and help

Comment: Perhaps your PHP installation is old and does not support the bracket [] arrays? Try replacing $rangeLabels = ["$0 - $100,000", etc...]; with $rangeLabels = array("$0 - $100,000", etc...); If that doesn't work, revert and post the original error.

Comment: Hi wedstorm, after playing about with both answers and adding more code and more data to the above including on pages aswel i finally got there, I very much appreciate you taking your time out to help me and i thank you for doing so. I feel bad that i can not accept both answers as the top answer as you have put your own time into helping and including the time to write the code. I have accepted msfoster as the top answer only because he was the first to provide such code and was the first to get me where i needed to be. I will keep an eye out for you on other posts and bump your answers up :)